# Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'

Tags: angular, ionic3

I don't know how to deal with this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'NgModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Cambio</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [ERROR ->][(NgModel)]="item.cambio" placeholder="e.g:"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

On imports, i have this code also:

```
 imports: [
    ...,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ...
```

I'm following this [course](https://www.udemy.com/create-a-crud-application-with-ionic-3-and-firebase/) on Udemy but there isn't any information about this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using:

```
[(NgModel)]="item.cambio"
```

when you should be using:

```
[(ngModel)]="item.cambio"
```

Change your template code like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Cambio</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.cambio" placeholder="e.g:"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Oh my god... cannot believe that... Thank you so much, VSCode didn't give me any error about that... (It takes me a little bit to see your differences jeje)

Comment: @M.Mariscal, Glad I could help. I understand. It's a very little change but a crucial one.

Answer (score 27):

if you are using `[(ngModel)]` and still getting this error, don't forget to import `FormsModule` in the current module

Comment: Besides the question is about the property being mistyped, this is the correct answer for those using ionic 4+ which uses new versions of Angular!

Comment: Works for me, but for the next person who needs the full import: `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`